# expo react native logout function not working properly

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am developing an expo react native application. There, I am facing an issue in logout. The logout tap is inside the profile section of the user. According to the current code, When I log in to the app for the first time, it redirects to the main navigation(Default menu). If I log in to the the app after log out it redirects to the profile section.

- I tried by navigate to the login section when logging out. It didn`t work.
- I tried by reloading the app each time when logging out. It worked for ios not for android. But I am feeling that it is not a good practice to do like that.

```
//Using navigation
logOutPress() {
        var _this =this;
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
            // Sign-out successful.
            _this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            AsyncStorage.clear();
        }
    }

//Reloading
logOutPress() {
        var _this =this;
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
            // Sign-out successful.

            AsyncStorage.clear();
            Platform.OS == 'ios' ? NativeModules.DevSettings.reload() : '';
        }
    }

 //Create the required screens in StackNavigator
        var theScreen = createStackNavigator({
          Master: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyMastSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} />) },
          Categories: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyCategoriesSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={item.category_first} subMenus={[]} />) },
          MasterSUB: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyCategoriesSreen data={{'categorySetup':item}} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} subMenus={item.subMenus} />) },
          Details: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyDetailsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true}/>) },
          DineIn: { screen:({ navigation})=>(<MyDineInScreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} />) },
          Gallery: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyGallerySreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          ForgetPassword: {screen: ForgetPassword},
          SignUp: { screen: SignUp }, 
          WebSub: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyWebSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} fromNotification={true} />) },
          NotificationsSub: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyNotificationsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          OrdersSub: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyOrdersSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          TicketsSub: { screen: ({ navigation }) => (<MyTicketSreen data={item} userEmail={this.state.userEmail} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          OrderDetail: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyOrderDetailSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design}/>) },
          DineInOrders: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyDineInOrderScreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} />) },
          // DineInOrderDetail: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyDineInOrderDetailScreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design}/>) },
          ProfileSettingsSub: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyProfileSettingsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          SubProfile: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyProfileSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />)},
          ProfileSettings: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyProfileSettingsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          ListOfUsersSub: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyListOfUsersSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          Chats: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyChatsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          Chat: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyChatSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />)},
          Gift: { screen: ({ navigation }) => (<MyGiftSreen data={item} userEmail={this.state.userEmail} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },


        },{
          //initialRouteName:item.category_first?"Categories":(item.subMenus&&(item.subMenus.length>0?"MasterSUB":"Details")),
          initialRouteName:initialRootName,
          headerMode:"none",
          navigationOptions: {
            headerTintColor: 'blue',
          }
        });
      }
```

The results I wanted is to open the default navigation instead of profile section when I log in to the app after log out. Please help to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show your default navigator setup, are you using `react-navigation`?

Comment: @AbdeenM. I have edited the code section with navigations. Can you please find it?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

I do not see a reference to your `Login` page on the stack so change `_this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');` to `_this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp');`

---

### **A better way of handling authentication and stacking your navigation**

1. Use `createSwitchNavigator` to handle your root stacks, for your application it would be something like this:

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
   {
      Loading: LoadingScreen,   // Include a loading screen that will check authentication state
      Auth: AuthNavigator,
      Main: MainNavigator
   },
   {
      initialRouteName: 'Loading',
      // Other configs
   }
)
```

2. The `AuthStack` this will have a all your login. signup, welcome, etc screens, something like this:

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
   {
        SignUp: { screen: SignUp },
        ForgetPassword: {screen: ForgetPassword},
        // Include other screens here if applicable
   },
   {
        initialRouteName: 'SignUp'
        // Other configs
   }
)
```

3. The `MainStack` this will have all your application screens, from what you showed on your question, it would look something like this:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
          Master: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyMastSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} />) },
          Categories: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyCategoriesSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={item.category_first} subMenus={[]} />) },
          MasterSUB: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyCategoriesSreen data={{'categorySetup':item}} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} subMenus={item.subMenus} />) },
          Details: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyDetailsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true}/>) },
          DineIn: { screen:({ navigation})=>(<MyDineInScreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} />) },
          Gallery: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyGallerySreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          WebSub: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyWebSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} fromNotification={true} />) },
          NotificationsSub: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyNotificationsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          OrdersSub: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyOrdersSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          TicketsSub: { screen: ({ navigation }) => (<MyTicketSreen data={item} userEmail={this.state.userEmail} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          OrderDetail: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyOrderDetailSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design}/>) },
          DineInOrders: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyDineInOrderScreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={true} />) },
          // DineInOrderDetail: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyDineInOrderDetailScreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design}/>) },
          ProfileSettingsSub: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyProfileSettingsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />) },
          SubProfile: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyProfileSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} isRoot={false} />)},
          ProfileSettings: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyProfileSettingsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          ListOfUsersSub: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyListOfUsersSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          Chats: { screen:({ navigation })=>(<MyChatsSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
          Chat: { screen: ({ navigation })=>(<MyChatSreen data={item} navigation={navigation} design={design} />)},
          Gift: { screen: ({ navigation }) => (<MyGiftSreen data={item} userEmail={this.state.userEmail} navigation={navigation} design={design} />) },
   },
   {
          initialRouteName: 'Master',   // <== Make sure to set this to the first screen you want on your application
          // Other configs
   }
)
```

4. The `LoadingScreen` this should look something like this:

```
class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId')
        this.props.navigation.navigate(userId ? 'Main' : 'Auth')   // This will check if there is any item stored with userId, if true it will navigate to Main else to Auth
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: 'white'
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.textloadingStlye}>Loading Screen</Title>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

5. The Authentication flow with `AsyncStorage`, when you first login or signup the user make sure to add this after a successful authentication and before navigating them to the Main screen, something like this:

```
.... // Firebase login, then
await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', id);   // <== Here id is what you want to store of the user data for authentication, could be his db id or name or whatever you have
this.props.navigation.navigate('Loading');
```

6. Your `Signout`, now finally for your sign out do:

```
logOutPress() {
   firebase.auth().signOut();   // <== This will signout from firebase
   AsyncStorage.clear();   // <== This will clear the userId from storage
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Loading');   // <== We navigate to the loading screen we set earlier, which will check if there is a userId and navigate accordingly 
}
```

**Note: Remember that your main Stack now in this setup is `AppNavigator` so make sure to cast `export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator)`**

Hope this Helps!